# How to know a NSString is already decoded from UTF8?

Tags: ios, utf-8, nsstring

I received data from server in json format, in which contain utf8 string. I use the following code to decode:

```
+ (NSString*)decodeUTF8String:(NSString*)utf8String
{
    if (utf8String == nil) return nil;

    const char* str = [utf8String cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    if (str == nil) return nil;

    NSString* res = [NSString stringWithCString:str encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return res;
}
```

In return, how can we know that a string is already decoded from UTF8? The thing is if we send a already decoded string to the above function, it will returns incorrect result (sometime it returns nil value).

For example:

```
json looks like this : { "name": "Innoviris Demo Session\u00c3\u00a9\u00c3\u00a9\u00c3\u00a9", ...} 

//- parse json
NSString* utf8String = @"Innoviris Demo SessionÃ©Ã©Ã©";

//- decode
NSString* decodedString = [self decodeUTF8String:utf8String]; //- decodeString = @"Innoviris Demo Sessionééé" ---> correctly

//- decode again
NSString* decodedString2 = [self decodeUTF8String:decodedString]; //- decodeString2 = nil ---> unexpected result
```

Comment: The code you posted tries to repair a broken `NSString`. A much better approach is not to create the broken string in the first place. Where do you get it from? Show the code that calls `decodeUTF8String:`. There is some code that converts an `NSData` that you actually get from the server to an `NSString`.

Comment: The way you asked the question does not really make sense: `NSString`s are always decoded (and provide a UTF-16 based interface).

Comment: I received a json that contains UTF8 encoded string. json looks like this : { "name": "Innoviris Demo Session\u00c3\u00a9\u00c3\u00a9\u00c3\u00a9", ...}. When it is stored in a nsstring, it looks like this: @"Innoviris Demo SessionÃ©Ã©Ã©", I use the above function, the string is converted into an expected value: @"Innoviris Demo Sessionééé"

Comment: Do you have any control over the source of that JSON? Because it's very broken and should be fixed.

Comment: I use RestKit for the webservice to fetch a json data. And I don't control over the source of that json: [RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];